# Cmake command error

Tags: raspbian-buster, debian

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B with the latest version of Raspbian (v. 5.4).

I am following this tutorial, [How to build a WiFi picture frame with a Raspberry Pi](https://opensource.com/article/19/2/wifi-picture-frame-raspberry-pi).
Which led to me to this github repo, nextcloud /
[client_theming](https://github.com/nextcloud/client_theming)

Within this repo I followed the Debian(Version 10.4) instructions and I am stuck on this step:

```
cmake -D OEM_THEME_DIR=$(realpath ../nextcloudtheme) -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr  ../client
```

The error that gets returned is:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi/client" does not exist.
```

Not to sure what this means, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you do `mkdir /home/pi/client; cmake ...;`?

Comment: that works however now I get an error that says: "make *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop"

The files in the folder are: "CmakeCache.txt, CmakeFiles, cmake_install.cmake, CMakeLists.txt, MakeFile

Comment: Then you need to go back to where you download the code and read the README instructions. They may differ from the blog item you started at,

Comment: Dougie, do you think I need to follow the "install debian" section before the build section on the github repo?

Comment: Your Raspberry Pi running RaspiOS Buster is booted from a DebIan derivative system. So NO.